# Expect Documentation

Tags: foreach, expect

I want to do the following in expect, but I cannot find documentation that either shows how to do this or explains that it cannot be done.

I want to have a set or array of words, eg: "pig", "chicken", "house", "room"

I then want to run the same command for every word, eg: "delete $word"

I assume this has to be done in a foreach loop, but both Google and Bing refuse to show me any links that have both the word "expect" and "foreach" on the same page. Any pointer to the documentation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What programming language are we talking about?

Comment: "expect" - the Linux command.

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay enough attention :)

Comment: I think I just had a major revelation... It looks like I can mix and match bash and expect.

Comment: Thats great. If you finded the solution consider to answer your own question and accept it. It can help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect is a Tcl extension, so the Tcl documentation is highly relevant: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm

```
foreach word {pig chicken house room} {
    delete $word
}
```

Comment: You will benefit from reading the Tcl tutorial: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize it was Tcl. That explains why bash syntax almost works. I will use Tcl syntax instead.